# Microsoft Graph API, PowerShell code to get a list of compliant devices for a user

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell, microsoft-entra-id

I am trying to come up with PowerShell code to get a list of compliant devices for a given user. So far, I have below code working to get the list of computers for a given user:

```
Connect-AzureAD
Connect-MgGraph 
$user = 'FName LName'
$user = Get-MgUser -Filter "Displayname eq '$user'"
$PrincipalName = $user.UserPrincipalName
$Id = $user.Id
Write-Host User Principal Name: $PrincipalName
Write-Host User Id: $Id
$devices = Get-MgUserOwnedDevice -UserId $Id
foreach ($device in $devices) {
        Write-Host "Device Id: $($device.Id)"
$test = get-MgDevice -DeviceId $device.Id 
Write-Host $test.DisplayName
}
```

But I would also like to include a filter to the get-MgDevice cmdlet to get only the compliant devices.

I tried to replace

```
$test = get-MgDevice -DeviceId $device.Id
```

with this one:

```
$test = Get-MgDevice -Filter 'isCompliant eq true' -ConsistencyLevel eventual -CountVariable c  -DeviceId $deviceId
```

But it doesn't work and errors out.
Could someone suggest how I can accomplish my goal? Any help is very much welcome and appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have one user named **`Sri`** with 2 devices where 1 is **complaint** among them like this:

[image]

When I ran your code to list the devices of given user, I got **response** like this:

```
Connect-MgGraph -NoWelcome
$user = 'Sri'
$user = Get-MgUser -Filter "Displayname eq '$user'"
$PrincipalName = $user.UserPrincipalName
$Id = $user.Id
Write-Host User Principal Name: $PrincipalName
Write-Host User Id: $Id
$devices = Get-MgUserOwnedDevice -UserId $Id
foreach ($device in $devices) {
        Write-Host "Device Id: $($device.Id)"
$test = get-MgDevice -DeviceId $device.Id 
Write-Host $test.DisplayName
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

To get a list of only **compliant** devices for a given user, you can make use of below *modified* PowerShell script:

```
Connect-MgGraph -NoWelcome

$userName = 'Sri'
$user = Get-MgUser -Filter "Displayname eq '$userName'"
$userId = $user.Id

Write-Host "User Principal Name: $($user.UserPrincipalName)"
Write-Host "User Id: $($userId)"

$devices = Get-MgUserOwnedDevice -UserId $userId

$compliantDevices = 0

foreach ($device in $devices) {
    $deviceId = $device.Id
    $test = Get-MgDevice -Filter "id eq '$deviceId' and isCompliant eq true"
    
    if ($test) {
        $compliantDevices++
        Write-Host "Device Id: $($test.Id)"
        Write-Host "Device Name: $($test.DisplayName)"
    }
}

Write-Host "Number of Compliant Devices: $($compliantDevices)"
```

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: How do I get the compliance status like "Yes" or "N/A" as in the screenshot in your response

Comment: Could you please post a new question regarding this with more details including screenshot and share link here?

Comment: I just posted a new question as suggested. Thanks.

Comment: Your new post is closed as you missed including code that you tried. While posting new question, make sure to include the PowerShell code that you are currently using.